# Notation for two-vertex graph with m edges

Tags: graph-theory, notation

Is there standard notation for the graph on two vertices with $m$ edges between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an another (and arguably better) reference, which uses different notation.  In Section 8.1.3 of [Handbook of Discrete and Combinatorial Mathematics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0849301491) by Rosen, this graph is called the dipole graph (of size $m$) and denoted by $D_m$.

Answer (score 2):

On page 578 of [Graph Theory (Graduate Texts in Mathematics)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1846289696) by Bondy and Murty, this graph is called an $m$-bond and denoted by $B_m$.

Comment: This is also the terminology I was familiar with. Although if you use this, you should definitely mention the definition you are using, since bond is often used to refer to a minimal edge-cut.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is fairly standard to use $\lambda K_n$ to denote the complete multigraph (the graph on $n$ vertices, with $\lambda$ edges between every pair).

Comment: Ok. This sounds vaguely familiar. Can you provide a citation for this?

Comment: That notation is also used for $\lambda$ disjoint copies of $K_n$, so you should make sure to specify the notation you are using.

Comment: @TysonWilliams just google complete multigraph, and a few papers come up. The Bondy-Murty notation would be fine too (I forgot that I had seen it in there as well). Whatever notation you decide to use, you'll still probably need to define it in your writing somewhere.

Comment: Yes, I will certainly define the notation.  I was just hoping to use something that the reader might already be familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

A **graph** consists of two classes: 
The class of **arrows** (or **edges**) and
the class of **objects** (or **vertices**) and 
two mappings from arrows to objects, called **source** and **target**(or **domain** and **codomain**).

Thus a graph may also be thought of as a **functor** $F$ from the category 
$
\space *
\begin{matrix}
\rightarrow\\ 
\rightarrow
\end{matrix}
*\space
$ to $Sets$.

A graph with 2 vertices and m edges is then an above functor $F$ with
$$|F(arrows)|=m$$
$$|F(objects)|=2$$

Comment: Sure, but you didn't give notation for this specific functor.

Comment: Lets take $\lambda F_n$ for the Graph with $\lambda = |F(arrows)|$ and $n = |F(objects)|$.

Comment: Did you just make up this notation or is it standard?  Also, this notation is essentially the same as that suggested by Casteels but he didn't need category theory to define it.

Comment: I recently read this definition of a graph seen as a functor (it is just fun in this context, so don't take this too serious).

Comment: Oh, sorry.  I didn't realize that your answer was meant as a joke.